# SQL How to get records until one record is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL 2008

I don't even know how to word this, but here I go; I'm trying to get first record with flag = 1, and the following records up until the next record flag = 1, so record 1 trough 5 would be one set, record 6 and 7 another set and record 8 trough 10 another set.

```
RECORD  FLAG
1           1
2           0
3           0
4           0
5           0
6           1
7           0
8           1
9           0
10          0
```

I was thinking about using a cursor, loop or something like it, but I cant get it to work.

Here's what I have tried:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT RECORD,FLAG
FROM TABLE 
WHERE FLAG = 1

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Records   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

  --HERE IM LOST-- HOW TO GET THE RECORDS THAT FOLLOW THE FIRST RECORD WITH FLAG=1

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Records  
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: What RDBMS and version? What do the desired results look like? You want to bring back all 10 rows. Or just one of the sets? And if so which one?

Comment: What do you want to do with these "sets" of rows? Can't you simply loop over the rows with a cursor and detect which rows are the first one of a set to do something special? What if the first row doesn't have FLAG=1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach a new value that identifies each group of records.  This new value is the cumulative sum of `flag`:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.flag)
        from table t2
        where t2.record <= t.record
       ) as grp
from table t;
```

This is standard SQL and can then be used in any query.  So, if you want the first group, you can do:

```
select record, flag
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.flag)
              from table t2
              where t2.record <= t.record
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
where grp = 1
order by record;
```

SqlFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40bf7/4

EDIT:

You don't mention the database.  In some databases (Oracle, Teradata, DB2, Postgres, and SQL Server 2012), you have a cumulative sum.  It would typically look like this:

```
select t.*, sum(flag) over (order by record) as grp
from table t
```

This syntax does the same thing.

Comment: +1 for the approach taken ( using the cumulative `SUM` of `flag` )